# Kannel step-by-step installation tutorial

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sms, gateway, kannel

I've been trying to install Kannel opensource gateway for sending free sms on my computer. But I never managed to make it work by reading the guide from the official website. So I'm starting over and interested in all information I can get.

- What hardware do I need?
- Can I install it on Ubuntu 12.04?
- Could someone post a link of a good tutorial, or write one here on step-by-step Kannel installation.

Edit:
Also, an example of sms sending using a php script would be appreciated.

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am concerned about your idea of "sending **free** sms on my computer".

While Kannel can be used to send SMS from your computer, you will require one of that :

- a GSM modem ([What is a GMS modem](http://www.nowsms.com/faq/what-is-a-gsm-modem))
- a [Phones that works as SMSC's with Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/compatibility.shtml)
- an account with a SMSC (Short Message Service Centre. The system responsible for storing and forwarding messages).

A SMSC will probably charge you for the services. Using a GSM modem or Phone means you have a valid SIM, linked to a paid mobile phone plan.  Either way, you will pay someone.

There are packages available for Ubuntu 12.04 [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/kannel).

And here is a [good tutorial](http://thuannvn.blogspot.ca/2009/01/setting-up-configuring-and-using-kannel.html) on installing Kannel from source and configuring it, using a GSM modem.